# Facebook App Invite does not open my application if it is installed on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I crated an App link by using Facebook's [App invite creator](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) then I replaced the requirements codes in my Application.

```
 String appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/XXXXXXXXXXX";
                String previewImageUrl = "http://letspepapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/app_invitation.png";

                if ( AppInviteDialog.canShow() ) {
                    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                            .setApplinkUrl( appLinkUrl )
                            .setPreviewImageUrl( previewImageUrl )
                            .build();
                    AppInviteDialog.show( mActivity, content );
                }
```

Then My app started to invite on Facebook. It is simpler.

The problem is when users get invite from their facebook friends. Even though The application is installed in user's phone When user click on the invite, Google play page is opened.

It is my app link page

[image]

Then I replaced the codes below in Androidmanifest.xml
[image]

I read thorough [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) but I think I miss a finer point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Within the manifest declare the intent-filter like this:

```
<data android:scheme="letspepapp"
          android:host="invitefriends" />
```

Comment: I have the same issue, this does not help, Facebook shows windows with install app from play market